# Difference between import and require in jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am writing my first test for a react-native project using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) and [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)

My code is something like

```
jest.autoMockOff();
jest.setMock('react-native', {
    NativeModules: {}
});
jest.setMock('react-native-router-flux', {
    Actions: {}
});

const mockStore = require('../../mock/Store');
const actions = require('../myActions');
...
// Some tests that test if the right actions are dispatched.
```

The above works, However when I use ES6 `import` instead of `require` I have a problem.

If I replace

```
const actions = require('../myActions');
```

with

```
import * as actions from "../myActions"
```

I get the below error.

```
Runtime Error
  - Error: Cannot find module 'ReactNative' from 'react-native.js'
        at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-resolve/src/index.js:117:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js:175:25)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-router-flux/src/Scene.js:10:18)
```

While I can work with this, I am curious to understand the reason for failure,
Also note that I am just not able to transpile `react-native-router-flux` with `es2015` presets in `.bablerc` file and I think I will have to live with that limitation (of not being able to transpile react-native-router-flux).

myActions.js looks like

```
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
export function searchRequest() {
    return {
        type: "search_request"
    }
}

export function searchRequestFailure(error) {
    return {
        type: "search_request_failure",
        error: error.toString()
    }
}

export function searchRequestSuccess(payload) {
    return {
        type: "search_request_success",
        payload: payload
    }
}

export function search(nameOrAddress) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(searchRequest())
        return fetch("http://localhost:8080/search", {
            method: "GET"
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        }).then((responseData) => {
            dispatch(searchRequestSuccess(responseData))
            Actions.list() //react-native-router-flux dependency
        }).catch(error =>  {
            dispatch(searchRequestFailure(error))
        })
    }
}
```

Using react-native 0.26 and jest 12.1.1

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct ES6 conversion.

```
const actions = require('../myActions'); // requires the defaultMember of the exported module and

//ES6 (ES2015) equivalent is 
import actions from '../myActions';
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

Comment: The link says `import * as name from "module-name"` is a valid syntax; I dont have a default export in `myActions`, so I need to wild card import all actions from it.

Comment: I have edited the description to include myActions.js

Comment: The error does not seem to related the import line then. How do you use you actions ? Can you share that code as well?